# AngularJS getting value from function in ng-if and using that value in element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-if

My question lies in the following code. Though the code is not working now. I wan't to rewrite it in proper way so that it works.

```
<span ng-if="community = vm.getCommunity(invite.community_id)!=null" grv-icon-comm-type="vm.communityViewHelper.getTypeIcon(community)" ng-class="vm.communityViewHelper.getColorClass(community)"></span>
```

In the above code `vm.getCommunity(invite.community_id)` returns either `null` or `community` object. If `community` object is returned then I wish to call two more function in the same element where I wish to use the recently received`community` value on those two function.

It's just killing my time. Please help.

Comment: Add parentheses. Currently, it's equivalent to `community = (vm.getCommunity(invite.community_id) != null)`. I.e. community is a boolean. You want `(community = vm.getCommunity(invite.community_id)) != null`.

Comment: Be vary of placing too much logic into the view. Apart from being (in my opinion) a bad practice, assigning values in the `ng-if` directive, could cause unforeseen issues. Instead I'd move this logic to the controller: `vm.community = vm.getCommunity(invite.community_id);` and then in your view do something along the lines of this `ng-if="vm.community"`.

Comment: I'm getting <code>community</code> not null but my main problem is using the value in the following portion: <code>grv-icon-comm-type="vm.communityViewHelper.getTypeIcon(community)"</code> That was the main question actually.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a watcher on "invite.community_id" to set community inside a controller function. Could look a bit cleaner depending on the rest of the code.
This function could even set all three values if you like.